# react-beautiful-dnd and constraints to allow only certain positions in a list

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I want to sort a list of elements with dependencies, and so I want to allow only certain positions of an element in the list.

for example:

```
x <--|
- A  |  I want to disallow C to be before A
- B  |
- C -
- D
```

I didn't find how to do that during the drag & drop. I just can disallow the action of the drop, and so the list is unchanged.

any help would be appreciated.

Frédéric

Comment: Did you try [conditional dropping](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd#conditionally-dropping)? I think what you want to accomplish is somewhat like in [this example](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?selectedKind=onDragStart&selectedStory=toggle%20isDropDisabled%20onDragStart&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel), with additional restrictions for dependency tree levels

Comment: thanks; yes, I tried. when I disabled the dropping after the move exceeds a limit, the "destination" of the next move is null, and so I can't do any move, even if I move back to an allowed zone

Comment: You can check [this two-level example](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?selectedKind=complex%20vertical%20list&selectedStory=nested%20vertical%20lists&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) do get a grip on how to handle disabling by type. This way you can move your tasks only within tree levels.

Comment: Could you manage some solution in the end?

Comment: no, I found no solution. do you have one ?

Comment: I also have similar issue.. In my case I also want the user to not drag same items